Jersey : 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header gets encoded
From my site's user interface, I call back end API that is running through Jersey HK2 and I have following code in the filter:
final String origin = httpRequest.getHeader("origin");
httpResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);

Now, I see the following headers being sent and received in Chrome's developer toolbar:
Request Headers:
Origin: https://example.com:8443

Response Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https%3A%2F%example.com%3A8443

I want to avoid escaping/encoding of non-alphanumeric characters. Do I need to change anything in the implementation?

Can you check that the httpRequest.getHeader("origin") value is correctly retrieved and is not encoded. Log the origin value to confirm its format.
System.out.println("Origin Header: " + origin); // For debugging

If it's encoded can you decode and add
final String origin = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(httpRequest.getHeader("origin"), "UTF-8");


